# React component elements/data not rendering but logs in console

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I have a component Blog.js that fetches data from [this API](http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/blogs/) . My code looks like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// const BLOGS_URL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/api.vidyarajkumari.com/blogs/";
const BLOGS_URL = "http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/blogs/";

export default function Blog() {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(BLOGS_URL);
      setBlogs(request.data.blogs);
      return request;
      }
    fetchData();
    }, [])  

  return (
    <section className="colorlib-blog" data-section="blog">
      <div className="colorlib-narrow-content">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
            <span className="heading-meta">Read</span>
            <h2 className="colorlib-heading">Recent Blog</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
        {
          blogs.map((item, index) => {
            console.log(item);
            return (
              <div key={index} className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                <div className="blog-entry">                    
                  <a href="#" className="blog-img project">
                    <img 
                      src={item.feature_image} 
                      className="img-responsive img-fluid img-thumbnail fit-image" 
                      alt="Blog image"
                      style={{width: "100%", height: "30rem", objectFit: "cover"}}
                    />
                  </a>                    
                  <div className="desc">                      
                    <span><small>{item.created_at} </small> | <small> {item.category} </small> </span>
                      <h3><a href="#">{item.title}</a></h3>
                      <p>{item.excerpt}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 animate-box">
          <p><Link to="/blogs" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-load-more">View all blogs</Link></p>
        </div>
        <hr className="col-md-12" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  )
}
```

What I observe is that I can see the data for the JSX elements from the `item` object being logged in the browser console but the elements are not rendered on my development server. I can even see the outlines of the elements when I hover over with the browser inspector tool. What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was with the class "blog-entry" inside the div tag within the JSX returned, and not because of failure to fetch the data from the api. Changing/removing it solved the problem.